# Remove duplicate in Excel using formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data like below in a Excel file

```
            ID     country   before phone    after phone       extra phone
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            1        Au       cell 12345x23     c12345x23        
            1        Au       cell 12345x23                    c12345x23
            2        us       cell # 123456     c123456
            2        us       cell # 123456      
            3        uk       cell 09823         c09823
```

I would like to achieve result like this: That is, I have to keep the row that has either "after phone" OR "extra phone" exists.

```
            ID     country   before phone    after phone       extra phone
            --------------------------------------------------------------

            1        Au       cell 12345x23                    c12345x23
            2        us       cell # 123456     c123456   
            3        uk       cell 09823         c09823
```

How can I achieve this? Note: Looks like Excel provided remove duplicate is not working here.

Comment: There are two records for `ID` 1, both of which have either after or extra phone numbers.  Why was only one of them retained in your expected output?

Comment: You could use a simple `IF` statement to create a "helper column" indicating which rows to keep, then sort by that column, and delete the appropriate rows - that is, *if* your criteria made more sense. According to your description, **both** records ID#1 should be kept since they both have `after` and `extra`, yet you've removed one of them in the 2nd dataset. Also what would happen if neither `after` nor `extra` exists? And, what about [`Filter for unique values`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2)

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert one temporary column between 'before phone' and 'after phone'.
2. Name it as "sort".
3. Insert this formula `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(E3)),1,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(F3)),2,3))` this formula will setup priority 1st to after phone, 2nd to extra phone and 3rd to non.
4. Select all data
5. Go to Data ribbon > Sort and Filter > Sort (New window will open)
6. In sort by drop down, select ID.
7. Press Add level button.
8. Select Sort.
9. Go to Data ribbon > Data Tools > Remove Duplicates
10. Click 'Unselect all' and check box "ID, Country, Before Phone"
11. Press OK button

    - This process will keep only first row and will delete all remaining rows pertaining to that ID, country and before phone.